# How do I replace a multiline string in sed with a placement with leading spaces

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with lines like

```
 something 
-----------
```

where there's a leading and trailing space after `something`. I want to replace it with

```
 other 
-------
```

and preserve the leading and trailing space. How?

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i '/^ something $/{:a;N;/^--*$/M!ba;s/something/other/}' file
```

Gather up lines between the start and end markers, then replace the required string with the alternative.

N.B. Uses the `M` flag to make an exact match within multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines, **that is all**, for anything else you should be using awk:

```
$ awk 'n{$0=substr($0,1,n); n=0} {sub(/^ something $/," other "); n=length()}1' file
 other
-------
```

That will work with any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can match multiple lines with a comma separated set of regexps. And substitute everything in the range with the `c` command. To get the `c` command not to ignore leading white space, use a backslash after it. e.g.

```
sed -i.original '/^ something $/,/-----------$/c\ other \n-------' input-filename
```